# how to make awk add correctly when commas are used as digit group separators

Tags: bash, awk

I'm trying to use awk to add up the numbers from an output file, but it seems awk doesn't understand the commas separating the thousands.

For example, running

```
awk '{if($1=="foo") {SUM+=$2}}END{print "foos ",SUM}'
```

on

```
foo 70.31
foo 125.00
foo 1,750.00
```

returns

```
foos 196.31
```

What's the best/appropriate way in awk to add these up correctly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
awk '{if($1=="foo") {gsub(",", "", $2); SUM+=$2}}END{print "foos ",SUM}'
```

Or, if you don't want to clobber `$2`:

```
awk '{if($1=="foo") {TERM=$2; gsub(",", "", TERM); SUM+=TERM}}END{print "foos ",SUM}'
```